# What's the difference between ACTION_CANCEL and ACTION_UP in MotionEvent?

Tags: android, motion, motionevent

I want to track a finger touch on the screen. So what I did was to start recording the position when `MotionEvent` triggers `ACTION_DOWN`, but how do I know when the action is finished, at `ACTION_CANCEL`, or `ACTION_UP`?

What's the exact difference between them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[MotionEvent:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

- ACTION_UP: A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate points since the last down or move event.
- ACTION_CANCEL: The current gesture has been aborted.

ACTION_CANCEL occurs when the parent takes possession of the motion, for example when the user has dragged enough across a list view that it will start scrolling instead of letting you press the buttons inside of it. You can find out more about it at the viewgroup documentation: [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

so use ACTION_CANCEL when the action is dragged out of the parent, and ACTION_UP otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In general `ACTION_UP` is triggered by user when the guest is finished to definitely indicate that the user completed interacting with movement.

On the other hand `ACTION_CANCEL` is called by Android system to indicate that one of views took control using `onInterceptTouchEvent()` which returned true as a result system finished propagating the touch event.

Please take a look at a [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222691/4770877)