# How are Android touch events delivered?

Tags: android, events

I'm not asking how to handle touch events, but what is going on behind the scenes? If there are several nested widgets, what order do they see the events in? Does the developer have any control over it? Ideally I would like a document on the subject.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From Activity viewpoint:

Touch events are delivered first to Activity.dispatchTouchEvent. It's where you may catch them first.

Here they get dispatched to Window, where they traverse View hierarchy, in such order that Widgets that are drawn last (on top of other widgets) have chance to process touch in View.onTouchEvent first. If some View returns true in onTouchEvent, then traversal stops and other Views don't receive touch event.

Finally, if no View consumes touch, it's delivered to Activity.onTouchEvent.

That's all your control. And it's logical that what you see drawn on top of something else, has chance to process touch event before something drawn below it.

Comment: Do you have any kind of document describing this?

Comment: About dispatching: I can read source code and function comments.
About order of View traversal - I've read it in some document, certainly on developer.android.com, but can't exactly tell now which.

Answer (score 148):

Let's take a look at a visual example.

[image]

When a touch event occurs, first everyone is notified of the event, starting at the Activity and going all the way to the view on top. Then everyone is given a chance to handle the event, starting with the view on top (view having highest Z order in the touch region) and going all the way back to the Activity. So the Activity is the first to hear of it and the last to be given a chance to handle it.

[image]

If some ViewGroup wants to handle the touch event right away (and not give anyone else down the line a chance at it) then it can just return `true` in its `onInterceptTouchEvent()`. An Activity doesn't have `onInterceptTouchEvent()` but you can override `dispatchTouchEvent()` to do the same thing.

If a View (or a ViewGroup) has an `OnTouchListener`, then the touch event is handled by `OnTouchListener.onTouch()`. Otherwise it is handled by `onTouchEvent()`. If `onTouchEvent()` returns `true` for any touch event, then the handling stops there. No one else down the line gets a chance at it.

## More detailed explanation

The above diagram makes things a little more simple than they actually are. For example, between the Activity and ViewGroup A (the root layout) there is also the Window and the DecorView. I left them out above because we generally don't have to interact with them. However, I will include them below. The description below follows a touch event through the source code. You can click a link to see the actual source code.

*(Update: the source code has been updated so the line numbers are off now, but clicking the links will still get you to the right file. Just do a search for the method name.)*

1. The Activity's [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3288) is notified of a touch event. The touch event is passed in as a `MotionEvent`, which contains the x,y coordinates, time, type of event, and other information.
2. The touch event is sent to the Window's [`superDispatchTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/Window.java#1593). `Window` is an abstract class. The actual implementation is [`PhoneWindow`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#1241).
3. The next in line to get the notification is DecorView's [`superDispatchTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/DecorView.java#444). `DecorView` is what handles the status bar, navigation bar, content area, etc. [It is actually just a `FrameLayout` subclass](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/DecorView.java#113), which is itself a subclass of `ViewGroup`.
4. The next one to get the notification (correct me if I'm wrong) is the content view of your activity. That is what you set as the root layout of your activity in xml when you create the layout in the Android Studio's Layout Editor. So whether you choose a `RelativeLayout`, a `LinearLayout`, or a `ConstraintLayout`, they are all subclasses of `ViewGroup`. And ViewGroup gets notified of the touch event in [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#2473). This is the **ViewGroup A** in my diagrams above.
5. The `ViewGroup` will [notify any children](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#2983) it has of the touch event, including any `ViewGroup` children. This is **ViewGroup B** in my diagrams above.
6. Anywhere along the way, a `ViewGroup` can [short-circuit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#2504) the notification process by returning `true` for [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3123).
7. Assuming no `ViewGroup` cut the notifications short, the natural end of the line for the notifications is when the View's [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](http://%60dispatchTouchEvent()%60) get's called.
8. Now it is time, to start handling the events. [If there is an `OnTouchListener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/view/View.java#7379), then it gets the first chance at handling the touch event with [`onTouch()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/view/View.java#17783). [Otherwise](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/view/View.java#7384), the View's [`onTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/view/View.java#8302) gets to handle it.
9. Now all the ViewGroups recursively up the line get a chance to handle the touch event in the same way that `View` did. Although, I didn't indicate this in the diagram above, a `ViewGroup` is a `View` subclass, so everything I described about `OnTouchListener.onTouch()` and `onTouchEvent()` also applies to ViewGroups.
10. [Finally](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3295), if no one else wanted it, the Activity also gets the last chance to handle the event with [`onTouchEvent()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3024).

## FAQ

**When would I ever need to override `dispatchTouchEvent()`?**

Override it in the Activity if you want to catch a touch event before any of the views get a chance at it. For a ViewGroup (including the root view), then just override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()`.

**When would I ever need to override `onInterceptTouchEvent()`?**

If you just want to spy of the touch notifications that are coming in, you can do it here and return `false`.

However, the main purpose of overriding this method is to let the ViewGroup handle a certain type of touch event while letting the child handle another type. For example, a `ScrollView` does this to handle scrolling while letting its child handle something like a Button click. Conversely, if the child view doesn't want to let its parent steal its touch event, it can call `requestDisallowTouchIntercept()`.

**What are the touch event types?**

The main ones are

- `ACTION_DOWN` - This is the start of a touch event. You should always return `true` for the `ACTION_DOWN` event in `onTouchEvent` if you want to handle a touch event. Otherwise, you won't get any more events delivered to you.
- `ACTION_MOVE` - This event is continuously fired as you move your finger across the screen.
- `ACTION_UP` - This is the last event of a touch event.

A runner up is `ACTION_CANCEL`. This gets called if a ViewGroup up the tree decides to intercept the touch event.

You can view the other kinds of MotionEvents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). Since Android is multi-touch, events are also fired when other fingers ("pointers") touch the screen.

## Further study

- Android onTouchEvent [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYoN-OvdZ3M), [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOcznwNEBf4), and [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIWQn90av54) (YouTube video - good summary of some of the links below)
- [Mastering the Android Touch System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) (thorough video by Google developer)
- [Android UI Internal : Pipeline of View's Touch Event Handling](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2014/03/pipeline-of-android-touch-event-handling.html)
- [Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) (Android docs)
- [Input Events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) (Android docs)
- [Gestures and Touch Events](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Gestures-and-Touch-Events)

Comment: Clarification on 8. If the View has an `OnTouchListener` **and** the listener's `onTouch(...)` returns false, then the View's `onTouchEvent(...)` is called next. If the View does not have an `OnTouchListener` then the View's `onTouchEvent(...)` is called.

Comment: Thank you Suragch, you are the best!
 I suppose you got all this information entirely from the official docs, isn't it?

Comment: @Harsha, I learned it by reading (and watching) the further study links and by walking through the source code step by step.

Comment: So I think your idea is to have a very detailed understanding of the concepts involved in Android architecture. I on the other hand have just read a java book, and am managing to write apps from the tutorials for each concept. I don't even follow/understand practices in code design, what would you suggest is the right way to learn for a serious programmer?

Comment: @Harsha, there is no need to learn the details like that unless you find you need it. The only reason I did was because I was making a custom view where I had to override the scrolling behavior at certain times. Keep doing what you are doing.

Comment: What about the View's/ViewGroup's onClickListener, when does he get a chance to repsond?

Answer (score 8):

**Android Touch event**

I have prepared a high level diagram that should illustrate a simple flow.

[image]

[image]

- `dispatchTouchEvent()` - `Activity`, `ViewGroup`, `View`
- `onInterceptTouchEvent()` - `ViewGroup`
- `onTouch()` - `ViewGroup`, `View`. Using `setOnTouchListener()`
- `onTouchEvent()` - `Activity`, `ViewGroup`, `View`

[[iOS onTouch]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61874084/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

following Suragch's answer,

pseudocode:

```
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean consume = false;
        if (onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) {
            consume = onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            consume = child.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        return consume;
    }
```

ref:Android开发艺术探索

Comment: Yes, that is the basic logic, though the ViewGroup does more processing than that.