# onTouchListener warning: onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have created a `onTouchListener`. Unfortunately onTouch() method `throws` me a warning:

> ```
> com/calculator/activitys/Calculator$1#onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected
> ```

What does it mean? I have not found any information about this warn. Here is the full code:

```
LinearLayout llCalculatorContent = (LinearLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.calculator_content);

llCalculatorContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Tools.hideKeyboard(getActivity(), getView());
        getView().clearFocus();
        return false;
    }   
});
```

Comment: you want to get rid of the warning just call `v.performClick()`. The implementation will play a little sound (if you have it enabled on your device) and call the onClickListener, that you probably have not overridden

Comment: Your answer was correct. Thank you

Comment: Hello @TrzyGracje is it okay if your can share the following class: Tools.hideKeyboard(getActivity(), getView()); The "Tools" Class

Comment: Hello @EmmanuelNjorogeOdongo. I worked on that project more than 6 years ago and I don't have access to it anymore. I am sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //some code....
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        v.performClick();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be called only when the event==MotionEvent.Action_UP , or something like that? Also, wouldn't returning "false" actually call the original clicking method, so you should actually return "true" instead?

Comment: @longilong Well if you wish you can also set it to use switch-case, but that's logically the same...

Comment: I have a similar warning. But my scenario is a little different since I'm setting an anonymous OnTouchListener when setting up the RecyclerView (calling myRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener. 
Android Studio is marking the whole anonymous class with a similar warning and even if I add v.performClick the warning remains.

Comment: if we return false from this method, we shouldn't be required to call `performClick`, right? In this case I don't understand why the lint warning is still there

Comment: Does nothing to fix the warning.

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier It won't solve the warning unless your custom view declares `onPerformClick()`

Comment: @secko I can't see it's making the click event :-(

Comment: I think this will not work when you have to listen double taps, drag, etc

Comment: doesn't fix the warning

Comment: It fixes the warning (at least for view's `setOnTouchListener`), but when press `SwitchCompat` it doesn't change it's state. And when press `Button` it executes an actione twice. So it would be better to move `v.performClick()` before `return`. Also change to `return false` or `return v.onTouchEvent(event)`. I think, we should remove `performClick()`.

Answer (score 10):

> onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected

You can suppress this Lint warning

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

You should call `performClick()` inside `onTouchEvent()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //Logic 
    performClick();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.view1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.performClick();
        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

[[OnTouch flow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222691/4770877)

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views.html#custom-touch-events)

Comment: You don't have to override `performClick()`. Please share your code

Answer (score 5):

*In case you're not using a `Custom View` which explicitly overrides `onPerformClick` , the warning won't get removed by just following Secko's answer.*

In addition to his answer, for doing the same on classes like `android.widget.Button` or `Button` you need to make a simple custom view which extends the target view.

**Example :**

*The Custom View Class:*

```
public class UselessButton extends AppCompatButton {
    public UselessButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UselessButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UselessButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return super.performClick();
    }
}
```

*XML* :

```
<stackoverflow.onEarth.UselessButton
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
```

*Java* :

```
    left.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            enLeft = 1;
            enRight = 0;
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            enLeft = 0;
            v.performClick();
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Current problems : Warning gets resolved by IDE, but can't see this practically performing click action on a real Android Device.

**EDIT**: Fixed getting the click event : Use `View.setPressed(boolean)`

```
down.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        enFront = 0;
        enBack = 1;
        left.setPressed(true);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        enBack = 0;
        v.performClick();
        v.setPressed(false);
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: does setPressed(false) ensure the performClick() will not somehow override if return false? i have code where return false, so viewpage should not go to specified tab. but since v.performClick() is called, it still goes to the tab and overrides it.

Answer (score 2):

just call performClick method, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.performClick();
    Tools.hideKeyboard(getActivity(), getView());
    getView().clearFocus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this warning by using Kotlin Extensions

First create the extension (Eg. ViewExtensions.kt)

```
fun Button.onTouch(touch: (view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent) -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        touch(v,event)
        v.performClick()
        true
    }
}
```

Second, in your Fragment or activity create a function

```
private fun onTouchButton(v: View, event: MotionEvent) {
       /* My Amazing implementation */
}
```

Finally, use the extension

```
myButton.onTouch { v, event ->
 onTouchButton(v, event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a `MultiTouchListener` and solved it implementing a `GestureDetector` and listening for a `SingleTap` (This does not remove the warning but starts to triggering `onClick` events on my view)

```
class TouchListener(context: Context) : MultiTouchListener() {

    private var tochedView: View? = null
    private var mGestureDetector = CustomGestureDetector()
    private var gestureDetector: GestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, mGestureDetector)

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(view: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val aux = super.onTouch(view, event)

        tochedView = view
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)

        return aux
    }

    private inner class CustomGestureDetector: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            // this will be called even when a double tap is
            tochedView?.performClick()
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e)
        }

        override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            // this will only be called after the detector is confident that the
            // user's first tap is not followed by a second tap leading to a double-tap gesture.
            tochedView?.performClick()
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is super late answer but I hope it will help somebody. I faced this warning a while ago and my approach was, made a class extending `View.class` then made a public method inside that class called it `closeKeyboard(View view){}` this is how it looks:

```
public class MyTouchEvent extends View {

    public MyTouchEvent(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void closeKeyboard(View view) {
        view.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
            view1.performClick();
       // this is a library handels the closing of keyboard
            UIUtil.hideKeyboard((Activity) getContext());
            return false;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        return true;
    }
}
```

in the `MainActivity` I called the `closeKeyboard(view)` and used the parent layout as parameter like this:

```
new MyTouchEvent(this).collapseKeyboard(parentLayout);
```

the library used to close the keyboard

```
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC2'
```

[library source](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent)

Answer (score 0):

I had to ignore it.  I had a TouchListener to cause an animated button push (change color in my case).  But I also had a click listener to do the button work.  So this caused my click listener to fire again.  I tried it as a default case in the switch of Touch Events (Action_Down, Up, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Just return `false` in `onTouch`method.

Doing so will not consume the event, which means that it will not prevent either `onClick` or `onLongClick` events from being invoked. Then, you do not have to call either `performClick` or `performLongClick`:

```
View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
    // do your work
    return false
}
```

---

**More Details**

If you really need a fully customised touch behavior rather than the default one in Android, then you should call perform methods by returning `true`. For example:

```
/**
 * A custom touch event which does not detect long clicks...
 */
View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
    // do your work
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        v.performCLick()
    }
    return true
}
```