# Why does Android Studio suggest that onTouch call view.performClick?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm getting the following suggestion on my `ouTouch()` function:

[image]

why is this?

Comment: are you overriding onTouch only? or creating a whole new custom view?

Comment: overriding onTouch only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are overriding onTouch listener and you are not calling performClick when clicks are detected, the View may not
handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should
ideally be placed in View#performClick as some [accessibility services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) invoke
performClick when a click action should occur.
so to get rid of the warning you have to call  `v.performClick();`

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        v.performClick();
        break;
```

or

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is suppress a warning

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

or call `performClick()`

[[Example]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57022629/4770877)