# Gridview touchListener for only visible cells

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I am making a game. I use `GridView` to display game blocks of various shapes ( tetris-like). So I have for example L block, T block etc.

When player touch and press on a block, he can move it anywhere on the screen. Each block is actualy a GridView, which has few cells colored and few invisible (depends on the block shape).

[image: ms paint image]

The problem occurs, when the blocks are near to each other, and you want to move a block which is "under" other blocks. Because of the gridView shape, touching at 1 or 2 position of the green block will not trigger green block touch listener, but blue (since the blue block was placed after the green on the layout, and you are touching inside its boundaries). So the player will start moving the blue block, but of course he wanted to move the green.

How can I fix this problem?

*Edit:*

I tried to set touch listener to every Blocks `gridView` child (don't mind empty cells at this moment), and pass the information to the methods I made. However, `ACTION_DOWN` works, but once I move my finger, the `ACTION_UP` is triggered (without any `ACTION_MOVE`).

```
void setBlockTouchListener(final Block block)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < block.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        block.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("TAG", "child down");
                        onDown(block, X, Y, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.d("TAG", "child cancel");
                        onCancel(block, X, Y, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("TAG", "child move");
                        onMove(block, X, Y, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat (when I try to touch and move the block):

```
child_down
child_cancel
```

Comment: Could you explain again please ? I don't understand. Do you want to listen just colored cells ?

Comment: Exactly. However when I set up a listener for each cell of the gridView, I don't receive further events from it.

Comment: Is "MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK" code necessary ?

Comment: It's used to separate the actual action and pointer identifier, but yes it's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)) after

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

Another view may be stealing the touch events. This will disallow the theft.

```
Block block = ((Block) v.getParent());

switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        block.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        onDown(block, X, Y, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        break;
        }
```

Comment: Okay so I found out this step you described is not neccessary for me, but `block.getLayoutParams().width = somevalue` (that's what I do in onDown) is the line which "consumes" the touch event and triggers `ACTION_UP`. Would you please have any suggestion how to listen even after changing layout width & height? By the way, I call `requestLayout()` too after changing params to apply them.

Comment: @BlackJack If you want to change the size of the block, you might try using [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) instead of the layout params. `                block.animate().scaleX(1.1f).scaleY(1.1f).start()' will grow the view by 10% and should not cause a cancel. I think once this is solved, my answer will be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the animation instead of params, and now it is possible to drag and move the blocks on the layout as before. But only one thing is still not working, and that's touchListener on cells under empty cells (figure 1), even I set listener only to cells which are actually displayed (empty cells have visibility `GONE` and no touchListener). When i touch that cell, no block gets touch focus. Other cells works fine. And to not forget, in the end I need the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEven` as you said, so it is in code too.  PS: I really want to give you bounty, just...

Comment: @BlackJack Even though the cell is `GONE`, the `Block` which is the `ViewGroup` holding the cell is taking the touch event. Add an override in `Block` for `onTouchEvent()` and always return `false`. This will permit the underlying cell to get control.  Take  a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862320/6287910) for more info.

Comment: Tried it now, but still no change. I'll take a look at the example you posted.

Comment: All blocks views are in a RelativeLayout, returning false in onTouch of a block would pass the event to the RelativeLayout if I am not wrong.

Comment: @BlackJack Return `false` in `onTouchEvent()` not `onTouch()`. The `Blocks` are stacked. If the top block refuses the touch (`onTouchEvent()` returns `false`), then the event moves down to the underlying view which, in this case, would be the color cell under the `GONE` cell. It would then have a bite at the apple and will be able to capture the touch stream to move its `Block`.

Comment: You are right. I overrided `onTouchEvent` and now passing the event seems to go correctly, empty cells now refuses the touch which goes under. Thanks for your help and patience.