# How to make area editable/not editable using Togglebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-togglebutton

I was trying to make an area so when ToggleButton is on, you are able to toggle buttons within this area and if ToggleButon is off, you won't be able to toggle the buttons within this area.

For this specific area I used a FrameLayout, so I can stack two LinearLayout on top of each other. So when I hit the Edit-Button, the one on top which is half transparent disappears with `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and you are now allowed to click the buttons now.

PROBLEM: The buttons in this area are always clickable

I was able to toggle them separately with `button.setClickable(true/false)` but is there a solution so you just  can't click through the LinearLayout that is on top (like "not-through-clickable")?

Link to an image of the Layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J19Y.png

Desired behavior:

Hit EDIT -> half transparent Layout on top of blue Layout disappears -> TESTOFF1 and TESTOFF2 are now clickable.
-> Hit DONE -> the half transparent Layout appears on top again and the buttons below it are not clickable anymore (without using `.setClickable` for every single button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view on top gets first crack at any touch events. If the top view doesn't handle the touch then the view below get a chance on down to the bottom view. The top layer is a `LinearLayout` so, but default, it doesn't handle touches, so it allows the touch events to percolate down to the buttons which are happy to respond.

One way to resolve this is to place a [touch listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) on the semi-transparent view that just returns true. Thus, the `LinearLayout` will consume the events and not let the buttons see them.

When the view is gone, the buttons become the top view so they will see the clicks.

If you want to know more about how touch events are handled, read [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449799/how-are-android-touch-events-delivered/46862320#46862320) for an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
editButton.setOnClickListener {
    button1.isEnabled = !button1.isEnabled
    button2.isEnabled = !button2.isEnabled
    editButton.setText(
        if (button1.isEnabled) {
            R.string.done
        } else {
            R.string.edit
        }
    )
    transparentView.isInvisible = button1.isEnabled
}
```

This example is using kotlin and the Android KTX libraries

Java version

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
    button1.setEnabled(!button1.isEnabled());
    button2.setEnabled(!button2.isEnabled());
    editButton.setText(button1.isEnabled() ? R.string.done : R.string.edit);
    transparentView.setVisibility(button1.isEnabled() ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing as well, I'm just not that familiar with kotlin.