# RecyclerView without touch events on top of other views (overlay)

Tags: java, android

I want to create a layout with multiple recyclerviews that are scroll-synced (already working) and on top of the whole LinearLayout which contains these recyclerviews I want to have another recyclerview (overlay) also scroll-synced with the others (already working).

Now my problem:
**The overlay should ignore all Touch/Click-Events like it is not there. The views inside the linearlayour should react to them (working without overlay).**

I tried to get it to work with onIntercerptTouchEvent and dispatch TouchEvents to the other views but I don't have a guess how to get it working.

My Layout:
`vertical_layout` contains multiple `Recyclerviews` as mentioned

```xml
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vertical_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/channels_layout">
            </LinearLayout>

            <CustomOverlayRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/overlay_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/channels_layout"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your custom *RecyclerView* add the following override:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```

This will prevent the custom *RecyclerView* from receiving further touch events and direct them to underlying views. See this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449799/how-are-android-touch-events-delivered/46862320#46862320) for an explanation about how this works and links to other resources.

Comment: I spent hours of hours searching for a solution and even read through the post you linked, but I didn't realize the solution is so simple... Thank you **very** much!!