# How to detect the type of scroll and then assign the touch to vertical or the inner horizontal scroll view

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a RecyclerView which has a several View Holders and some of them are horizontally scrolling. To improve the usability of my application, I need to detect the scroll based on angle (say 30 degrees to X axis) and depending on that, assign that to child's Horizontal scroll or let it's parent's vertical scroll handle it.

From @suragch's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862320/10165076, I understood we can intercept the touch event of the parentView, but I have a hard time coding that. If you can please help me here, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: Going further deep into usability, I need this to work smoothly even when the parent view is moving with the momentum of the fling.

Of the apps that I know, the Play Store app handles this perfectly, I tried to search for a solution online, but none of them could provide an approach that works as well as the Play Store does.

Comment: I am not sure if you can even call a RecyclerView a parent to it's ViewHolders. Please do let me know.