# Button left in highlighted state with touchListener and clickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button, ontouchlistener

I'm having a problem with my Button staying in a highlighted state, after doing the following:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Test", "calling onClick");
            }
        });
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        v.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                        v.invalidate();
                        v.performClick();
                        Log.d("Test", "Performing click");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Concerning the code above, when using it, I'm expecting the button click to be handled by the touch, and by returning "true" the handling should stop at the touchListener.

But this is not the case. The button stays in a highlighted state, even though the click is being called.

What I get is:

```
Test - calling onClick
Test - Performing click
```

on the other hand, if I'm using the following code, the button is clicked, same prints, but the button doesn't end up stuck in a highlighted state:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Test", "calling onClick");
            }
        });
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        v.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                        v.invalidate();
                        // v.performClick();
                        Log.d("Test", "Performing click");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to what's the responder chain to the touch event. My guess is that it's:

1) TouchListener

2) ClickListener

3) ParentViews

Can someone confirm this as well?

Comment: What you actually want to do, is it handling by touch or change color on just press?

Comment: I want to run some logic in touch and then call performClick and for it not to change the color of the button.

Comment: @Whitebear Please check the answer below. Maybe I can add more information.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449799/how-are-android-touch-events-delivered/46862320#46862320) might help you with understanding the flow of touch events. It's not clear what you want to occur. Do you want a click handler and to do the perform click? Do you want the button to go from its initial color to the state set by the color filter then back to its initial color?

Comment: Let me explain what I mean. I have a touchListener and a clickListener on the button. The touch precedes the click by priority and returns true if it handled the event, which means that no one else should handle it. This is exactly what I'm doing through the touch, handling the click and returning true, yet the button still stays highlighted even though it's onclick listener is called and the flow is done correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such customizations need no programmatically modifications. You can do it simply in `xml` files. First of all, delete the `setOnTouchListener` method that you provide in the `onCreate` entirely. Next, define a selector color in the `res/color` directory like the following. (if the directory doesn't exist, create it)

**res/color/button_tint_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#e0f47521" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Now, set it to the button's `app:backgroundTint` attribute:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/button_tint_color" />
```

### Visual Result:

[image]

---

## EDITED: (to address touch event issue)

From an overall point of view, the flow of the touch event starts from the `Activity`, then flows down to the layout (from the parent to the child layouts), and then to the views. (LTR flow in the following picture)

[image]

When the touch event reaches the target view, the view can handle the event then decide to pass it to the prior layouts/activity or not (returning `false` of `true` in `onTouch` method). (RTL flow in the above picture)

Now let's take a look at the [View](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java)'s source code to gain a deeper insight into the touch event flows. By taking a look at the implementation of the [`dispatchTouchEvent`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#13923), we'd see that if you set an `OnTouchListener` to the view and then return `true` in its `onTouch` method, the [`onTouchEvent`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#15284) of the view won't be called.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // removed lines for conciseness...
    boolean result = false;    
    // removed lines for conciseness...
    if (onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event)) {
        // removed lines for conciseness...
        ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        if (li != null && li.mOnTouchListener != null
                && (mViewFlags & ENABLED_MASK) == ENABLED
                && li.mOnTouchListener.onTouch(this, event)) { // <== right here!
            result = true;
        }
        if (!result && onTouchEvent(event)) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    // removed lines for conciseness...
    return result;
}
```

Now, look at the [`onTouchEvent`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#15284) method where the event action is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. We see that perform-click action happens there. So, returning `true` in the `OnTouchListener`'s `onTouch` and consequently not calling the `onTouchEvent`, causes not calling the `OnClickListener`'s `onClick`.

There is another issue with not calling the `onTouchEvent`, which is related to the pressed-state and you mentioned in the question. As we can see in the below code block, there is an instance of [`UnsetPressedState`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#28204) that calls [`setPressed`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#11956)`(false)` when it runs. The result of not calling `setPressed(false)` is that the view gets stuck in the pressed state and its drawable state doesn't change.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // removed lines for conciseness...
    if (clickable || (viewFlags & TOOLTIP) == TOOLTIP) {
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // removed lines for conciseness...
                if ((mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_PRESSED) != 0 || prepressed) {
                    // removed lines for conciseness...
                    if (!mHasPerformedLongPress && !mIgnoreNextUpEvent) {
                        // removed lines for conciseness...
                        if (!focusTaken) {
                            // Use a Runnable and post this rather than calling
                            // performClick directly. This lets other visual state
                            // of the view update before click actions start.
                            if (mPerformClick == null) {
                                mPerformClick = new PerformClick();
                            }
                            if (!post(mPerformClick)) {
                                performClickInternal();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (mUnsetPressedState == null) {
                        mUnsetPressedState = new UnsetPressedState();
                    }
                    if (prepressed) {
                        postDelayed(mUnsetPressedState,
                                ViewConfiguration.getPressedStateDuration());
                    } else if (!post(mUnsetPressedState)) {
                        // If the post failed, unpress right now
                        mUnsetPressedState.run();
                    }
                    // removed lines for conciseness...
                }
                // removed lines for conciseness...
                break;
            // removed lines for conciseness...
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[UnsetPressedState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#28204):**

```
private final class UnsetPressedState implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setPressed(false);
    }
}
```

Regarding the above descriptions, you can change the code by calling `setPressed(false)` yourself to change the drawable state where the event action is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                // v.invalidate();
                v.setPressed(false);
                v.performClick();
                Log.d("Test", "Performing click");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for my friend. I'm looking to understand the change in behavior in both situations I described above. If there's something I can elaborate about, please let me know. I don't want to delete the touch handler nor the click handler. Please check out my comment to the answer above.

Comment: @Whitebear: I've updated the answer. Please check it out, dude.

Comment: That's a good detailed answer, and I'd accept it. A few pointers to change: 
```Now, look at the onTouchEvent method where the event action is MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. We see that perform-click action happens there. So, returning true in the OnTouchListener's onTouch and consequently not calling the onTouchEvent, causes not calling the OnClickListener's onClick.```
In my case the onClick is called. 
mUnsetPressedState checks if it's null before setting to false and also the runnable is not sure to run if we're prepressed. I don't quite understand how you deduct that it should be set to false

Comment: The `onClick` is called because you are calling `v.performClick();`. Please check the above code in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` section again, `setPressed(false)` is called anyway, whether `mUnsetPressedState` is null or not, whether `prepressed` is true or not. The difference is in the way of calling `setPressed(false)` that could be through `post`/`postDelayed` or directly.

Answer (score 2):

You are messing around `touch` and `focus` events. Let start with understanding behavior with same color. By default, there is `Selector` assigned as background to the `Button` in Android. So simply changing background color, make is static (color will not change). But it's not a native behavior.

`Selector` might look like this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" />
</selector>
```

As you can see above, there is state `focused` and state `pressed`. By setting `onTouchListener` you will handle touch events, which have nothing to do with `focus`.

`Selector` of the Button should replace `focus` event with `touch` during click event on the button. But in first part of your code you intercepted events for the `touch` (returning true from callback). Color change cannot proceed further and is freezing with same color . And that is why second variant (without interception) are working fine and that is  your confusion.

**UPDATE**

All you need to do it's to change behavior and color for the `Selector`. For ex. by using next background for the `Button`. **AND** remove `onTouchListener` from your implementation at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/color_pressed" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/color_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: How would you change the first example to work well then?

Comment: Im not looking to remove the touch listener from my implementation. as I want to catch clicks on a specific view using the touch handler, and then handle them myself (using performClick) and return true from the touch listener in order to tell the other handlers that no further handling is done. The logs are printed fine in my example, yet the button still stays highlighted.

Comment: @Whitebear You didn't mentioned that in you questions. In any way, you can use as many `onTouchListener`s as you want. You just don't need to consume event, by `return true`.

Comment: @Whitebear **OR** Remove selector and set raw color to the button via `backgroundColor`.

Comment: guys, you still aren't addressing what I wrote in the original  post..

Answer (score 0):

if you assign a background to the button, it wont change the color on click.

```
 <color name="myColor">#000000</color>
```

and set it as backgrount to your button

```
android:background="@color/myColor"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use material Chips for instead of Button view. 
refer : https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip
there they handle those hililghted events and you can customize with applying the themes.