# How can I cancel the buttons contained in a LinearLayout from listening to clicks temporarily?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a bunch of buttons that depending on the state of the application don't make sense to listen to events. Is there a property/method on the LinearLayout or some other method that prevents its children buttons from listening to events? Of course I could go I search for a way to detach the events for each a every button but of course I want to go the easy and most handy way to do that. Also I could disable all the buttons. I've learned that disabled buttons don't listen to events in the hard way, when I tried to show a tost for a disabled button.

Comment: The LinearLayout has a property called setEnabled, I've tried and... guess what ... it didn't work!

Comment: you should not do this, sounds good but the best way is:

mybutton.sentEnabled = false 

Other options is to draw a dialog view to avoid interaction in your screen until the actions finished

Comment: I think the android was not architected to handle such complexities. A complex bubbling of events would waste resources. This is just a guess, I don't know nothing about Android engennering.

Comment: you are overthinking this . only dont do that.  always use native solutions. other solutions only are workaround .

Comment: Good read: [How are Android touch events delivered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449799/how-are-android-touch-events-delivered/46862320#46862320)

Comment: @BömachtBlau thanks for that link :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way which you can extend `LinearLayout` and override its [onInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method and return `true` if you want to steal touch events from its children or `false` if you want its children to receive touch events. Something like this

```
class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    //...

    private preventTouchOnChildren = false;

    public void setPreventTouchOnChildren(boolean value) {
        preventTouchOnChildren = value;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
        if (preventTouchOnChildren) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ALTERNATIVE 1

Updated answer!
I have tested setting all click listeners to all view hierarchy as follows, using kotlin extension function on View class

```
private fun View.dissableClick() {
        setOnClickListener(null)
        if (this is ViewGroup) {
            for (v in children) {
                v.setOnClickListener(null)
            }
        }
}
```

So you can call `root.dissableClick()`

You can also try using `isEnabled = false` and `v.isEnabled = false` in place of `setOnClickListener(null)`

ALTERNATIVE 2 (Credit @Amin Mousavi Answer)

Also from this documentation [Manage touch events in a ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup#java). You need to create a custom view group in your case a custom LinearLayout

```
class InterceptLinearLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attr: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attr, defStyleAttr) {

    var intercept = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?) = when (intercept) {
        true -> true
        else -> super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

Note: If you don't provide overloads for all super constructors your app is going to crash

Change your xml from `<LinearLayout ...` to `<package.InterceptLinearLayout ...`

On your Activity grab reference to InterceptLinearLayout

```
root.intercept = true
```

Both solutions worked for me

Comment: the `clickable` attribute does not affect if the children react to click events or not. In other words, this does not work

Comment: Your using kotlin/java?

Comment: I am using Kotlin. I just attempted it in Java and it also does not work. Anyway, changing the clickable attribute on the layout does not intercept the click events of the children.

Comment: I still have one small comment, however. Instead of removing the `OnClickListener` of the `children` in _attempt 1_, set their `clickable` attribute to `False`. Since here you are setting the `clickable` attribute of the children, not the parent; therefore, it would take effect. I noticed you also said one can use `isEnabled` which is also good :)

Comment: Sure you can do that @Nizar

Comment: Yes, I am aware. It would be better than removing and resetting the click listener though. Also it would be better to switch case the type of the view therefore you would only be dealing with buttons