# What causes a MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL in Android?

Tags: android, debugging, motionevent

I am working through debugging some touch handling stuff on Android, and am trying to figure out why the MotionEvent sent to my View's `onTouchListener` contains a *cancel* action. I have not been able to find any documentation on its cause, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for debugging this problem - error codes, source code, or some general knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean by cancel action? What code are you using?

Comment: @0gravity, I mean if `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

"ACTION_CANCEL occurs when the parent takes possession of the motion, 
for example when the user has dragged enough across a list view that it will 
start scrolling instead of letting you press the buttons inside of it. 
You can find out more about it at the viewgroup documentation: [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)."

Hope that is the answer you are looking for:

Resources: [Motion Event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240719/whats-the-different-between-action-cancel-and-action-up-for-motionevent).

Comment: It also happens on rotation, which wasn't clear to me from the above.

Answer (score 20):

All you need is to call

```
requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

on the parent view, like this -

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch(motionEvent.getActio){
            }

            return false; 

         }
```

Source: [onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent only see ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592610/onintercepttouchevent-ontouchevent-only-see-action-down)

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_CANCEL` is triggered by ancestor to notify all descendants that they lost `onTouch` control and it's will be responsible for handling the next `onTouch` event. Usually it is caused when a descendant returned true in `onTouch` or `onTouchEvent` method but after that, during the next of touch event of gesture, an ancestor returned true in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`

[[Touch event flow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222691/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, TouchDelegate helped.

https://medium.com/android-news/android-change-touch-area-of-view-by-touchdelegate-fc19f2a34021

```
private fun changeTouchableAreaOfView(view: View, extraSpace: Int) {
val parent = view.parent as View
Observable.just(parent)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            val touchableArea = Rect()
            view.getHitRect(touchableArea)
            touchableArea.top -= extraSpace
            touchableArea.bottom += extraSpace
            touchableArea.left -= extraSpace
            touchableArea.right += extraSpace
            parent.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(touchableArea, button)
        }

/* In case you don't want to use Rx java
parent.post {
    val touchableArea = Rect()
    button.getHitRect(touchableArea)
    touchableArea.top -= extraSpace
    touchableArea.bottom += extraSpace
    touchableArea.left -= extraSpace
    touchableArea.right += extraSpace
    parent.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(touchableArea, button)
}
*/
```

}

Answer (score -1):

When the drag moves out of view rect, you get ACTION_CANCEL

Comment: This does not happen at all times, even when the finger is already outside the boundaries of the touched view ACTION_CANCEL won't be called but ACTION_UP.