# onInterceptTouchEvent's ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE never gets called

Tags: android

Log is never logging **ACTION_UP** or **ACTION_MOVE**(which i removed from the code example for shortening)

Here is my shorten version of the code:

```
 public class ProfileBadgeView extends LinearLayout {

    Activity act;

    public ProfileBadgeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ProfileBadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ProfileBadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void initView(Activity act) {
        //..init
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            logIntercept("ACTION DOWN");
        } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            logIntercept("ACTION_UP");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
}


    private void logIntercept(Object obj) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " INTERCEPT :", obj.toString());
    }



}
```

Comment: Put a Toast outside the conditions and check if the toast is displayed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `onInterceptTouchEvent` method is not called after `ACTION_DOWN` event because you return `true` in `onTouchEvent` method. So all the other events are sent in `onTouchEvent` and not in `onInterceptTouchEvent` any more:

> Using this function takes some care, as it has a fairly complicated
>   interaction with View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent), and using it requires
>   implementing that method as well as this one in the correct way.
>   Events will be received in the following order:
>
> You will receive the down event here. The down event will be handled
>   either by a child of this view group, or given to your own
>   onTouchEvent() method to handle; this means you should implement
>   onTouchEvent() to return true, so you will continue to see the rest of
>   the gesture (instead of looking for a parent view to handle it). Also,
>   **by returning true from onTouchEvent(), you will not receive any
>   following events in onInterceptTouchEvent() and all touch processing
>   must happen in onTouchEvent() like normal**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)