# Android onInterceptTouchEvent doesn't get action when have child view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, view

I have parent view v extends linear layout. And child one is *LinearLayout*, child two is *ScrollView*.

I want to make MyParent View intercept vertical **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** (only down direction, child `scrollview.getScrollY()==0`) and processing it in parent, and other *MotionEvent* is processed by children

Here is MyView.xml

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_linear>
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp">
            ...something...
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/child_scrollview>
      <LinearLayout/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </merge>
```

And this is my code below

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout{
    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MyView, this, true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        Log.d(log,"onInterceptTouchEvent : "+action);
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == 
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mIsBeingDragged = false;
            return false;
        }
        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && mIsBeingDragged) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (isReadyForPull()) {
                    final float y = event.getY(), x = 
event.getX();
                    final float diff, oppositeDiff, absDiff;
                    diff = y - mLastMotionY;
                    oppositeDiff = x - mLastMotionX;
                    absDiff = Math.abs(diff);
                    ViewConfiguration config = 
ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());

                    if (absDiff > config.getScaledTouchSlop() &&  
absDiff > Math.abs(oppositeDiff) && diff >= 1f) {
                            mLastMotionY = y;
                            mLastMotionX = x;
                            mIsBeingDragged = true;
                            Log.d(log,"Flag setting");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (isReadyForPull()) {
                    mLastMotionY = mInitialMotionY = event.getY();
                    mLastMotionX = event.getX();
                    mIsBeingDragged = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return mIsBeingDragged;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action=event.getAction();
        Log.d(log,"onTouchEvent : "+action);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getEdgeFlags() != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.d(log,"ACTION MOVE RECEIVE");
                if (mIsBeingDragged) {
                    mLastMotionY = event.getY();
                    mLastMotionX = event.getX();
                    pullEvent();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (isReadyForPull()) {
                    mLastMotionY = mInitialMotionY = event.getY();
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mIsBeingDragged) {
                    mIsBeingDragged = false;

                    if (mState == State.RELEASE_TO_REFRESH ) {
                        setState(State.REFRESHING);
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (isRefreshing()) {
                        smoothScrollTo(-mHeaderHeight , null);
                        return true;
                    }

                    setState(State.RESET);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`isReadyForPull()` function check only this

```
    private boolean isReadyForPull(){
        return mScrollView.getScrollY()==0;
    }
```

My code works well.

If I move down my child scrollview, `onInterceptTouchEvent` first get **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** and initialize values, and get sequentially **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** so set **mIsBeingDragged** flag to **true** and return **true**. So I can process event in my *ParentView*'s `onTouchEvent`.

Otherwise, if I move up child scrollview, then `onInterceptTouchEvent` return false and my child scrollview get that *MotionEvent* and scrolling down.

This is expected work. Good.

But, when I touch my child linearlayout, it doesn't not work!

If I touch and drag my child linearlayout, my CustomView's `onInterceptTouchEvent` get **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN**, but couldn't get second **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE**.

Why this not work on only child linearlayout?

Note: 
I tested several times and know that (default)touchable view or viewgroup (like button, scrollview etc.) do work with my code, while (default)untouchable view or widget(like imageview, framelayout) don't work with my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540006/3340395) answer, as it is a result of the standard `MotionEvent` handling.

In my code, when I touch the child `LinearLayout`, the parent `CustomViewGroup` doesn't intercept the `MotionEvent` as it returns false, but my child `LinearLayout` doesn't consume the `MotionEvent` either, so the `MotionEvent` is returned to the parent's `onTouchEvent`, not `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

On the other hand, when I touch my child `ScrollView`, it consumes the `MotionEvent` whether scrolling is enabled or disabled.

**==>** I think because Android doesn't generate a `MotionEvent` again until the original one is either consumed or finished, so the parent `CustomViewGroup` doesn't get the `ACTION_MOVE` `MotionEvent` via `onInterceptTouchEvent`, instaed it is piped to `onTouchEvent` when a child doesn't consume the `MotionEvent`.

I found two solutions

### Solution one

Forcibly make my `LinearLayout` consume the `MotionEvent`. This solution is available only when the child `LinearLayout` has no touchable `View`, `ViewGroup` or `Widget`. Like this:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.child_linear);
mLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

### Solution two

Process the `MotionEvent` returning from a child in my `CustomViewGroup`'s `onTouchEvent`. Like this: (Just add else if case in `onTouchEvent`).

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    if (mIsBeingDragged) {
        mLastMotionY = event.getY();
        mLastMotionX = event.getX();
        pullEvent();
        return true;
    }
    else if (isReadyForPull()) {
        final float y = event.getY(), x = event.getX();
        final float diff, oppositeDiff, absDiff;
        diff = y - mLastMotionY;
        oppositeDiff = x - mLastMotionX;
        absDiff = Math.abs(diff);
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());

        if (absDiff > config.getScaledTouchSlop() &&  absDiff > 
        Math.abs(oppositeDiff) && diff >= 1f) {
             mLastMotionY = y;
             mLastMotionX = x;
             mIsBeingDragged = true;
        }
     }
     break;
 }
```

While solution 1 is a quick fix for certain situations, solution two is the most flexible and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good answer

[onInterceptTouchEvent only gets ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283827/onintercepttouchevent-only-gets-action-down)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
MyLog.d(MyLog.DEBUG, "dispatchTouchEvent(): "+event.getAction());
if (isEnabled()) {
    MyLog.d(MyLog.DEBUG, "dispatchTouchEvent()2: "+event.getAction());

    processEvent(event);//here you get all events include move & up

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    return true; //to keep receive event that follow down event
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```