# How to disable touch of top transparent layer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, calendarview

I need to customise a Calendar having feature of Collapsing month view to week view. I am using `MaterialCalendarView` Library for this. For that i have taken a frame having `MaterialCalendarView` as a bottom layer and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` on the top as a transparent view. Now the problem is, i am not able to use my calendarView as it is a bottom layer and disable touch of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I have tried setting `android:clickable="false"` of `CoodinatorLayout` and all of its child elements and also tried using : `collapsingToolbarLayout.setEnabled(false);` and setting touch listener to false, but no luck.

This is my XML file:

```
-----some code-----
---
--
-
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:mcv_allowClickDaysOutsideCurrentMonth="false"
            app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
            app:mcv_tileHeight="36dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:focusedByDefault="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:focusedByDefault="false"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/dummy_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="72dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:focusedByDefault="false"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/dummy_toolbar_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:focusedByDefault="false" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="252dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:focusedByDefault="false" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/bg_dark_gray"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_occasions"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_login"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_50"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_30"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_50"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_100"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient_bg"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_16"
                        android:text="@string/next"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what i am doing in java file:

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setEnabled(false);
dummyToolbarView.setEnabled(false);
appBarLayout.setEnabled(false);
coordinatorLayout.setEnabled(false);

collapsingToolbarLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
      calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      return false;
});
appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
      calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      return false;
});
coordinatorLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
      calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      return false;
});
transparentView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
      calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      return false;
});
dummyToolbarView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
      calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      return false;
});


collapsingToolbarLayout.setClickable(false);
coordinatorLayout.setClickable(false);
appBarLayout.setClickable(false);
transparentView.setClickable(false);
```

After disabling touch of all the views, still onClick is getting called, that's why i have disable click also.

By doing this, i am able to handle touch of `MaterialCalendarView` when it is in collapsed mode, but when it is expanded then i am not able to use it, some other view is taking the click.

Please help me out with this. I want to access `MaterialCalendarView` touch and disable touch of views inside `CoordinatorLayout` except `NestedScrollView`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i ask, why it has been down voted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the efforts.

I resolved this by overriding dispatchTouchEvent. Thanks @Abyss for this post - Solution 2 works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971924/6384924

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

with dispatching touch of calendar on every view's touch

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
        dummyToolbarView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
        appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
        coordinatorLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
        transparentView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
        dummyToolbar.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            calendarView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`onInterceptTouchEvent` Responds to the parent layout touch events before they are dispatched to child views.

```
@Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
 // Decide if to intercept or not
 return true;
 }
```

[Touch flow control in Android](https://medium.com/@elye.project/understanding-android-touch-flow-control-bcc413e6a57e)

Comment: The method `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is only available on view groups (as they’re the one who can be parents/containers with the requirement to intercept touch events) that can sort of keep an eye on the event and hijack it by returning true. If it returns false then dispatching continues as usual.