# Forward touch events from custom View to ViewPager

Tags: android, user-experience

Let's say I have a ViewPager that takes 50% of screen height and a simple View (or other component) that takes other half of my screen. When I swipe on the View component I want my interaction to be visible on the ViewPager as if I was swiping on the ViewPager itself.

Any ideas how to implement this? I have tried overriding onTouchEvent in the View and then triggering onTouchEvent in the ViewPager, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: If you can settle for swipes on the `View` triggering page changes in the `ViewPager`, just [call `setCurrentItem(index, true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29) on the `ViewPager` when you detect the gesture in the `View`.

Comment: no, i want to see exact movement, setCurrentItem is not enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions myself. Here is how to do it:

1) Create a custom Class for your View that is instance of ViewGroup and overrides onInterceptTouchEvent(). Make sure that children of this ViewGroup return true onTouchEvent().

More explanation here: [onInterceptTouchEvent only gets ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283827/onintercepttouchevent-only-gets-action-down/13540006#13540006)

2) Inside onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) you have to forward the event to viewPager by calling viewPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)

Answer (score 0):

You can use special methods in ViewPager class:

- [beginFakeDrag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#beginFakeDrag())
- [fakeDragBy(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#fakeDragBy(float))
- [endFakeDrag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#endFakeDrag())